# Почему GridBagLayout групирует компоненты в центре?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Решил написать игру на Java AWT/Swing, которая на 70-85% будет состоять из текста (текстовая игра), чтобы закрепить изученное (я начинающий программист). Но почему-то GridBagLayout при увеличении размеров фрейма не масштабирует компоненты,а просто смещает их в центр. Можно ли это как-то исправить или это особенность GridBagLayout? Вот пример кода:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jfm = new JFrame("Test");
        jfm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        jfm.setLayout(gbl);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        jfm.add(new JButton("Начать игру"),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        jfm.add(new JButton("Об игре"),gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        jfm.add(new JButton("Выход"),gbc);

        jfm.setSize(250,250);

        jfm.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите сколько ячеек должен занимать тот или иной компонент

```
gbc.weightx = 1.0;
gbc.weighty = 1.0;
```

Когда weightx/weighty равен 0.0 (по умолчанию) GridBagLayout помещает любое дополнительное пространство между своей сеткой ячеек и краями контейнера.
[image: Масштаб изменяется]